# Lubuntu 13.10 - Polish letters on UK keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have netbook with UK keyboard (£ with 3, $ with 4, different placement of @ etc.) and I would like to have polish letters on this layout (Ctrl+s, Ctrl+a, ctrl+e etc.). It should be possible as I've set it up on different laptop with Windows 7. To set it up I need to create custom keyboard layout based on UK keyboard, I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `compose key`. Goto `System Settings> Keyboard Layout >Options`. Now click `Compose key position`, and choose for example the `Left win` key.

Now you should be able to do `Left-Win+n+'` to give `ń` etc. More sequences are given
[here](http://www.hermit.org/Linux/ComposeKeys.html).